# Using picklist to generate an ArrayList and find matching values in database

Tags: jsf

I have an array list named "newSymptomList" which contains a list of Symptom id's (e.g. [1,3,4]) generated by a pick list target. I want to go through each symptom and get the relevant symptom name from the database although I'm stuck on the while loop.

PickList:

```
<rich:pickList id="plID" listWidth="10em" 
                        value="#{sym.newSymptomList}" 
                        sourceCaption="Symptoms" 
                        targetCaption="Selected Symptoms">
                    <!--List of all Symptoms-->
                    <f:selectItems value="#{sym.allSym}" var="c"
                                   itemLabel="#{c.symptomName}" itemValue="#{c.symptomId}"/>
</rich:pickList>
```

Relevant code in SymptomBean:

```
private List<Symptom> newSymptomList = new ArrayList<Symptom>();

public List getNewSymptomList()
{
  return newSymptomList;
}

public void setNewSymptomList(List<Symptom> newSymptomList )
{
  this.newSymptomList = newSymptomList; 
}

//Here is the code which returns a list of matching symptom names:

public List getSymNames() {
    List selectedSymptoms= new ArrayList(); 
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = ...
        ps = con.createStatement();
        rs = ps.executeQuery("select * from symptoms");
        while (rs.getString(1)== newSymptomList) {
            //getString(1) is symptomID and getString(2) is symptomName
            selectedSymptoms.add(i,new Symptom(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
            i++;
        }
    }//end of try

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Data : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return selectedSymptoms;
}
```

Comment: Stuck because your getting an error?  Can't see how to create the query?  not sure what to loop through?  What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going in the wrong direction as to achieving the requirement. You have the symptom names **already** there in the `allSym` list as referenced by `<f:selectItems>`. Your mistake is that you're setting the selected symptoms as `List<Symptom>` while it should actually be a `List<String>` or whatever type the `#{c.symptomId}` actually is (it seems to be `String` as you're attempting to get it by `ResultSet#getString()`, which is not a sane type, but that aside), otherwise you would get a `ClassCastException` when iterating over it.

Fix it accordingly:

```
private List<String> newSymptomList; // +getter+setter.
```

Finally, you could just go through the `allSym` list which you already have there in the same bean to get the `Symptom` objects.

```
List<Symptom> selectedSymptoms = new ArrayList<Symptom>();

for (Symptom symptom : allSym) {
    if (newSymptomList.contains(symptom.getSymptomId())) {
        selectedSymptoms.add(symptom);
    }
}

// ...
```

Another way is to keep the `newSymptomList` a real `List<Symptom>` and fix the `itemValue` of your `<f:selectItems>` to be `#{c}` instead of `#{c.symptomId}`. You only need to implement a `javax.faces.converter.Converter` so that JSF will be able to automatically convert between `Symptom` and its unique `String` representation. For an example, see also [our `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info).

Comment: Thanks BalusC that helps a lot. I'm slightly confused as to where the for each statement as I keep getting an error on allSym?